# Why is there such a thing as a 6 chord when it is just an inverted minor 7?

Tags: chord-theory

Is there ever a time when a six chord is something other than an inverted minor 7 chord? Why do my songbooks have these chords notated this way when they are just inverted minor 7 chords?

Comment: …because the bassist would play the wrong note ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin As my guitar teacher used to say: " the good thing in playing the bass is that, of you make a mistake, it would sound like the guitar did something wrong..."

Comment: @Tetsujin In his short tutorial on walking bass Adam Neely says 6th can be treated as a chord tone. This makes the question even more interesting. Not sure why it received downvotes.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ruTfC5v9Z2Y (0:12)

Comment: @Tetsujin an inversion by definition means that the bassist IS playing a note other than the root as the bass so not sure what you mean

Comment: There may well *not* be a bass playing. It could well be just a piano or guitar chord.I think at that time, the chord would be named with regard to its lowest note.

Comment: In classical music analysis, I imagine CMaj6 would be viewed as having tonic function, while Amin6—even Amin6/C—would be viewed as having predominant function.  As indicated in Laurence Payne's answer, this has a lot to do with what the musical context is: Are we in tonic prolongation, or leading up to a dominant, or what?

Answer (score 2):

Am7 has ACEG, whilst C6 has CEGA. All the same notes, but not in the same order.

Now, does that matter in a chord? Not particularly, except the lowest note - in root poition/voicing - gives any chord its name (assuming it's not a slash chord - obviously!). So, with an A as the lowest note, it gets called Am7. If there's a C as the lowest, it gets called C6.

Ah, but what if the E or G is the lowest? It's still one of those - they both contain a root, third, fifth and another note, and that's how we define chord names, simply speaking. And why shouldn't that chord (whatever it is) have E or G as the lowest note. When playing bass, I may well use A, or C, but could, on a whim, or considering the next chord, throw in E or G instead or as well. So, it may depend on the technicality of what preceded and what follows. Again, either could be 'correct'. And following what the bassist 'ought' to play is probably the defining point.

Comment: The lowest note and the root are not the same thing. The root of the chord is the note that functions as the tonal center of the chord -- the pitch that sounds most stable within the chord. Am7 and C6, though they have the same pitches in them, are functionally different, because of whether, in context, they operate fundamentally as an A (minor) chord or a C (major) chord. As an example: a song is more likely to end G7 C6 than G7 Am7. On the other hand, the progression Am7 D7 GM7 in a bebop jazz tune is more likely that C6 D7 GM7. In practice, however, they're often written interchangeably.

Comment: @Tim If the  Am7 chord is in first inversion then wouldnt the bass player play C? else it is not an inverted chord is it? So not sure how what the bass plays has anything to do with it.

Comment: @armani - read my last comment. The same question will apply to an m6 chord and its (almost) twin - m7b5. E.g. Fm6 - Dm7b5.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  When playing a song in C major, there's a world of difference between the notes C, E, G, A (with C in the bass) as a final tonic chord and the same notes (with A in the bass) as part of a I, vi7, ii7, V7 progression.

Not that a guitarist, with a bass player, might not choose the same shape for each.   But they're harmonically quite different.  Listen...

[image]

What really distinguishes them is the harmonic context - what they DO in that piece of music.   As stand-alone chords they are indeed ambiguous.  But, in a piece in C major, as a final chord it's very likely to be the tonic, C6.    Whereas in the sequence C, *, Dm7 (or F), G7 it's going to be a lot more useful to call it Am7.

What it IS is the pitch set C, E, G, A.   What it DOES can tell us if it's more useful to think of it as C6 or Am7.

Comment: Thank you for the example. But the answer seems incomplete to me. Is the bass note the only thing that distinguishes Am7 from C6? What if in the first measure the bass plays other chord tones, E or G?

Comment: What really distinguishes them is the harmonic context - what they DO in that piece of music.   As stand-alone chords they are indeed ambiguous.

Comment: I'm thinking the same. But what harmonic context makes something C6 or Am7? Because that would be the answer for the question asked here.

Comment: @user1079505: Perhaps my 2020-07-13 comment on Tim's answer gives the harmonic context you're looking for.